# How to set the concurrencyMode using the new Bulk API 2.0

Tags: community, bulk-api, concurrency

I've read the documentation regarding the new **Bulk API 2.0** but I haven't found the way to send a request with the parameter `concurrencyMode` and set it to `Serial` instead of `Parellel`.

Can you help me ? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Setting the concurrencyMode in V2 is not possible.  I recently had the same issue and Salesforce support recommend using the V1 API to prevent the "row locking" issues we were having with V2.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the idea "Bulk API v2 support for Serial ConcurrencyMode"
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000cRQWQA2